# how to show item property in Feedzy

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

I have a xml file 
http://blog.brookfieldtx.com/rss.xml

and i would like to show the "Category" value with items.
By default I only can show post title and discerption. but I need the category too.

this is the short code

```
[feedzy-rss feeds="http://blog.brookfieldtx.com/rss.xml" 
 max="3" feed_title="no" target="_blank" refresh="12_hours" 
 title="40" meta="yes" summary="yes" 
 summarylength="300" thumb="yes" 
 size="100" default="http://your-site/default-image.jpg" 
 keywords_title="WordPress"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, since you haven't specified the formatting for the category name in the question you can modify it to display how you want it to appear.  Place this code in your **functions.php** file.

```
add_filter( 'feedzy_item_filter', 'add_feedzy_item_category', 20, 2 );

function add_feedzy_item_category( $itemArray, $item ) {
    if ( $category = $item->get_category() )
        if( $category->get_term() )
            $itemArray['item_meta'] .= '<br><strong>Category: ' . $category->get_term() . '</strong>';

    return $itemArray;
}
```

Comment: where I can find functions.php?

Comment: Make sure you build a child theme, don't overwrite the parent theme files.